# Type 'Any' has no subscript members (firebase)

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am getting this error: "Type 'Any' has no subscript members" when trying to run this block of code:

```
init(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) {
    key = snapshot.key
    itemRef = snapshot.ref

    if let postContent = snapshot.value!["content"] as? String {   // error
        content = postContent
    } else {
        content = ""
    }
}
```

I have been searching for an answer and couldn't find one that solved this problem with FireBase. How would I solve this error?

Comment: It looks like your snapshot has a primitive value, which means `snapshot.value` does not return a dictionary. Check what `key` is (I wouldn't be surprised if that is `content`) and what the JSON is at the location you are observing.

Comment: what does `print(snapshot.value!.dynamicType)` print?

Comment: @vacawama it prints that it is a NSDictionary

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`snapshot.value` has the type `Any?`, so you need to cast it to the underlying type before you can subscript it.  Since `snapshot.value!.dynamicType` is `NSDictionary`, use an optional cast `as? NSDictionary` to establish the type, and then you can access the value in the dictionary:

```
if let dict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary, postContent = dict["content"] as? String {
    content = postContent
} else {
    content = ""
}
```

Or, you can do it as a one-liner:

```
content = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)?["content"] as? String ?? ""
```

Comment: How do I get the values of the child nodes?

Answer (score 2):

I have also a codepiece which allows you to access to the values of the child nodes. I hope this helps you:

```
if let snapDict = snapShot.value as? [String:AnyObject] {

            for child in snapDict{

                let shotKey = snapShot.children.nextObject() as! FIRDataSnapshot

                if let name = child.value as? [String:AnyObject]{

                    var _name = name["locationName"]
                    print(_name)
                }

            }

        }
```

Best regards,
Nazar Medeiros