# Type 'Any' has no subscript members after updating to Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is my code in Swift:

```
currentUserFirebaseReference.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in
        let UID = snapshot.key
        let pictureURL = snapshot.value!["pictureURL"] as! String
        let name = snapshot.value!["displayname"] as! String
        let currentUser = Person(name: name, bio: "", UID: UID, pictureURL: pictureURL)
        self.currentUserInfo = currentUser
            })
```

I just updated to Xcode 8 / Swift 3, which seems to have caused the following error message:

> "Type 'Any' has no subscript members"

I call `snapshot.value!["`insert something here`"]` in many places in my code, I'm getting this error and I can't run my code.

The following code works:

```
let pic = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)?["pictureURL"] as? String ?? ""
```

However, I don't see what changed or what makes this necessary now versus how it was before.

The only thing that has changed as far as I'm aware is the syntax of the observe, but I don't understand why this caused my code to stop working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Type 'Any' has no subscript members (firebase)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39136026/type-any-has-no-subscript-members-firebase)

Comment: Thanks for correcting it Eric. There was a remaining reference to Objective C that I replaced with Swift too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In [FIRDataSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/interface_f_i_r_data_snapshot), `value` is of type `id`.

In [Swift 3](https://swift.org/migration-guide/), `id` is imported as `Any`.

In the Firebase documentation, it says `value` can be any of `NSDictionary`, `NSArray`, `NSNumber`, or `NSString` -- clearly, subscripting doesn't make sense on all of these, especially in Swift.  If you know it's an `NSDictionary` in your case, then you should cast it to that.

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Comment: An example of what?

Comment: To convert. I tried Hibernia's code and it worked well. However, I wan an example about what you say.

Answer (score 30):

J. Cocoe's answer is absolutely correct, but for those who need a code example this is how you do it:

instead of

```
let name = snapshot.value!["displayname"] as! String
```

try

```
let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
let name = snapshotValue["displayName"] as? String
```

The idea is that you need to cast the type of snapshot.value from Any to an NSDictionary.

Edit:

As Connor pointed out, force unwrapping snapshot.value or anything from a backend system is a bad idea due to possibly receiving unexpected information. So you change as! NSDictionary to as? NSDictionary.

Comment: Particularly with communicating with a backend like Firebase, I'd recommend not force unwrapping, in case that value isn't what you expect and you don't want your app to crash: `if let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary, name = snapshotValue["displayName"] as? String { \\ do stuff }`

Comment: Please don't use `NSDictionary` in Swift unless you have no choice. The native dictionary `[String:Any]` type is preferable because it provides type information.