# Swift 3 : Error: Type 'Any' has no subscript member

Tags: ios, swift, nsdictionary, swift3

I updated to Swift 3 and I get this error and I can't solve it.

> Type 'Any' has no subscript member

I already read the answers:

[39480150](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39480150/type-any-has-no-subscript-members-after-updating-to-swift-3) - [38956785](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38956785/type-any-has-no-subscript-members) - [39516199](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39516199/type-any-has-no-subscript-members-in-xcode-8-swift-3)

But I couldn't solve my problem with the answers.

This is my code:

```
let pathperdataselezionata = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Annuale", ofType: "plist")
let dictperdataselezionata = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: pathperdataselezionata!) as![String:AnyObject]
let valoridataodierna = dictperdataselezionata[annoscelto]?[mesescritto]?![daymonth?] as? [Double]
let Grad = Int(valoridataodierna![0])
let Ampo:Double = valoridataodierna![1]
```

And I get the error on the line:

```
let valoridataodierna
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: you have 3 subscripts for [String:AnyObject]. Is is supposed to be [String:[AnyObject]] ?

Comment: The compiler needs to know the types of **all** subscripted objects. And since the data comes from a file in the bundle why do you use question marks? If you get a runtime error your design is very bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this.

```
let dictperdataselezionata = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: pathperdataselezionata!) as! [String:[String:[String:AnyObject]]]
let valoridataodierna = dictperdataselezionata[annoscelto]?[mesescritto]?![daymonth?] as? [Double]
```

Comment: This has solved my problem. Thanks a lot. Due my reputation I can't accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Apple's recommendation is to use lots of variables, see: [Working with JSON in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37).

```
if let pathperdataselezionata = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Annuale", ofType: "plist"),
    let dictperdataselezionata = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: pathperdataselezionata) as? [String: Any],
    let dictAnnoscelto = dictperdataselezionata[annoscelto] as? [String: Any],
    let dictMesescritto = dictAnnoscelto[mesescritto] as? [String: Any],
    let daymonth = daymonth,
    let valoridataodierna = dictMesescritto[daymonth] as? [Double]
{
    let Grad = Int(valoridataodierna[0])
    let Ampo:Double = valoridataodierna[1]
}
```